# PyAutoGUI not returning correct rgb values

Tags: python, rgb, pixel, pyautogui

I am using python 3.9 with pyautogui==0.9.52 and I am trying to get the rgb value of a certain pixel on my screen. The results are something like, if I have the coordinate of a red pixel it returns the rgb value as `(30,30,30)`.

If I use `displayMousePosition()`, I first have to run `sys.platform = '_'` to even get a rgb value in the first place, and even then it is still the wrong rgb value.

If I use `pyautogui.pixel(x,y)`, it also returns the wrong rgb value. Does it have to do with incompatible versions maybe? Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: `displayMousePosition` sounds like it returns the position, not the pixel value. Where is that function defined/documented? What values are you getting for the pixels versus what you're expecting.

Comment: @Lburris12 Aren't you looking for `image = pyautogui.screenshot()` `x, y = pyautogui.position()` `rgb = image.getpixel((x, y))`?

Comment: @RandomDavis if I use displayMousePosition() it gives me updated output whenever I move the mouse. The output consists of the x and y coordinates of the mouse and the RGB value of the pixel that the mouse is on. When I use it, say I'm trying to get the value of an orange circle, I hover my mouse over the orange circle, but the RGB value returns something like (30, 30, 30).

Comment: @Guimoute I have also tried this but this also returns back an inccorect RGB value.

Comment: One thing that I might be helpful to know is that when I open python shell and import pyautogui it says, "UserWarning: rubicon.objc.ctypes_patch has only been tested with Python 3.4 through 3.8. You are using Python 3.9.0. Most likely things will work properly". If this is the problem anybody know how I can properly use this on python 3.9?

Comment: Did you try on a supported version of Python? What's forcing you to be on 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. I couldn't figure out why pyautogui returns (30, 30, 30) for all pixels but I found an alternative for pyautogui to get pixel color.

It is called win32gui `pip install win32`

```
def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    import win32gui
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(i_desktop_window_id,i_desktop_window_dc)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)
```

Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#Python

It returns accurate results. Example: (0, 127, 237).